# invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors

Tags: c++, function

I have done a little script were I testing arrays+functions+switch case in c++.

It isnt finished yet, but I ave a problem with my "enter or type in" function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int Groesse[6];
int Gewicht[6];
string Name[6];
int i;
int Auswahl;

void Eingabe(int WertA)
{
    cout << "Bitte die die Liste fuellen: " << endl;
    for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
        cin >> WertA[i];   
    }
    return WertA;
}

void Ausgabe (int WertB)
{
    cout << "Folgende Werte wurden eingegeben: "<< endl;
    for (i=0; i<=4;i++)
    {
        cout << WertB[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Bitte die Groessen eingeben: "<< endl;
    Eingabe(Groesse);
    cout << "Bitte das zugehoerige Gewicht eingeben: " << endl;
    for (i= 0; i<=4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Gewicht" <<i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> Gewicht[i];
    }
    cout << "Bitte den Zugehoerigen Namen angeben" << endl;
    for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
        cout<< "Name" <<i+1<<": ";
        cin >> Name[i];
    }

    cout << "Wonach wollen Sie suchen? Druecken Sie: " << endl;
    cout << "(1)Groesse oder (2) Name oder (3) Gewicht " << endl;
    cin >> Auswahl;

switch (Auswahl)
    {
    case ('1'):
       cout << "Geben Sie die Gesuchte nummer an von 0-4" << endl;
       cin >> i;
       cout << Groesse[i], Gewicht[i], Name[i];
       break;


    case ('2'):
       cout << "Geben Sie die Gesuchte nummer an von 0-4" << endl;
       cin >> i;
       cout << Groesse[i], Gewicht[i], Name[i];
       break;


    default:
        cout <<"Falsche Eingabe bitte Widerhollen" << endl;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in Line 19/21:
invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

and in the second function
main.cpp|29|error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript|

What should I do? I'm confused :(

Comment: "int WertA" is a single int. you can't get WertA[i] from it, because it's not an array.

Comment: And why do your void functions return? Do you not get warnings? If not, then turn them on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The comma does not do what you think it does. Look more closely at whatever examples you're learning from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, for example:

```
void Eingabe(int WertA)
{
    for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
        cin >> WertA[i];   
        ...
```

what do you expect to happen?

`WertA` is of type `int`, it's a number, and you are trying to index it like it was an array.

You could index it if the prototype was something like this:

```
void Eingabe(int* WertA)
```

which would indicate that `WertA` is an array of `int`s. Of course, outside of the function the array could look like this:

```
int WertA[4];
```

---

Moreover, you do later in that function:

```
return WertA;
```

while its return type is `void`, which should result in a compilation error.

Comment: ... As long as space for 4 ints was created outside the function :)